# RegEx matching between characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a String in Java. The splits should occur in between two characters one of which is an alphabetic one (a-z, A-Z) and the other numeric (0-9). For example:

```
String s = "abc123def456ghi789jkl";
String[] parts = s.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parts));
```

Output should be `[abc, 123, def, 456, ghi, 789, jkl]`. Can someone help me out with a matching regular expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of [look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String s = "abc123def456ghi789jkl";
String regex = "(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)";
String[] parts = s.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parts));
```